# Identifying all parent nodes in TreeView

Tags: c#, treeview, parent-child, parent

I have a tree that looks something like this:

```
+Parent
       -Child
+Parent
       -Child
       +Parent
              -Child
+Parent
+Parent
       +Parent
              +Parent
                     -Child
                     -Child... etc.
```

I need to be able to identify all the nodes that are parents, regardless of the level. Basically I need an `exampleTree.Nodes.GetAllParents()` method.

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? What do you mean identify? Do you mean iterate through and look at each one? Are you asking if there's a way to just "get all parents" ? We need more info to help you.

Comment: Yes, basically I'm asking if there's a way to do something like `exampleTree.Nodes.GetParents();` and I haven't really 'tried' anything, I'm researching a way, but so far I've not stumbled upon anything that's really useful.

Comment: I would update your post to reflect that, as its a little unclear and some people will probably downvote it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of extension methods that I use:

```
public static class TreeViewEx {

  public static List<TreeNode> GetParentNodes(this TreeView treeView) {
    List<TreeNode> results = new List<TreeNode>();
    foreach (TreeNode node in treeView.Nodes) {
      results.AddRange(GetNodes(node));
    }
    return results;
  }

  private static List<TreeNode> GetNodes(TreeNode parentNode) {
    List<TreeNode> results = new List<TreeNode>();
    if (parentNode.Nodes.Count > 0) {
      results.Add(parentNode);
      foreach (TreeNode node in parentNode.Nodes) {
        results.AddRange(GetNodes(node));
      }
    }
    return results;
  }

}
```

Usage would be as such:

```
List<TreeNode> parents = treeView1.GetParentNodes();
```

Comment: This looks like it might be useful, I'll give it a try and get back to you :)

Comment: @LarsTech Feel free.  These aren't the actual methods, but I cobbled this together from them (I don't need parents, just "all").